# How to detect end of stream in F#?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, stream

I have a F# function like the following:

```
open System.IO
open Microsoft.FSharp.Control.CommonExtensions

let rec copyData (ins:Stream) (outs:Stream) = async {   
    let! bytes = ins.AsyncRead(1)
    do! outs.AsyncWrite(bytes)
    return! moveData ins outs
}
```

When the `ins` stream reaches the end, it throws an `AtEndOfStream` exception. So I have to catch it in the calling function. How can I prevent this exception by detecting the stream is currently at the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `AsyncRead` overload that you're using here tries to read exactly the number of bytes you specified (and it fails if it reaches the end, because it cannot read the specified number of bytes).

Alternatively, you can use an overload that takes a buffer and returns the number of bytes read:

```
let rec copyData (ins:Stream) (outs:Stream) = async {   
  let buffer = Array.zeroCreate 1024
  let! bytes = ins.AsyncRead(buffer)
  if bytes > 0 then
    do! outs.AsyncWrite(buffer, 0, bytes)
    return! moveData ins outs
}
```

This overload does not throw an exception at the end of the stream, but instead it will return 0 (and it won't write anything into the buffer). So you can just check if the number of bytes read is greater than 0 and stop otherwise.

If the stream is closed already before calling `copyData` then you'll need to check for `CanRead` or handle the exception, but if the stream is open before calling `AsyncRead`, you'll just get 0 back.

Answer (score 1):

Just check the [`CanRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.canread.aspx) property, like so:

```
let rec copyData (ins:Stream) (outs:Stream) = async {
    if ins.CanRead then
        let! bytes = ins.AsyncRead(1)
        do! outs.AsyncWrite(bytes)
        return! moveData ins outs
}
```

Comment: This may work for some streams, but not all. For example, if the stream were created by `WebRequest.GetResponseStream` the exception still occurs when reaching the end.